# Can I install bought game on another mobile phone?

Tags: android

I was wondering if it's possible to install games that I own from my Google Play account and install them on my girlfriend's phone just by log in with my account on her phone.

Don't know if it's against there ToS since I can't find anything related to this on Google. I know this sounds illegal but maybe it's like a game that I've bought on PS3 and I let my GF play with.

But when I've purchase my other android phone, I just had to connect to Google Play with my account and I was able to download all my previous bought games. So I know I should be able but can I ?

Thanks for clarifying my question :D

**Update**

Found something [related](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38830/can-i-download-a-ps3-games-from-psn-on-my-own-system-and-then-download-the-same) for the PS3's Network that you can share with 2 console. Could it be the same for Android :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, if you authorize Google Play for her phone and you're OK with her using your account and having access to all of you downloads and payment method, then there shouldn't be an issue. If a piece of content has an activation limit, it will typically tell you. For instance I have purchased a backup application but it can only be active and installed on one device at a time. For the most part I believe Google leaves the limit selection up to the individual developer.

But, Google did recently implement a 10 device limit as you can read here:

http://support.google.com/googleplay/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1230356&topic=2450456&ctx=topic

You'll see tighter limits more active in the music and video areas as you can see here videos have a 5 device install limit, but can only be played by one device at a time:

http://support.google.com/googleplay/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2666462